# Measuring traffic sent and received over Internet

Tags: vb.net

How to measure the number of bytes sent and received while using the internet from VB.NET 2010 ?

Comment: No they are not, PHP and .NET is HOPEFULLY NOT SAME, and shame on people who - voted this, no such question exist for VB.NET

Comment: Which language are you actually working in? I reopened the question, but StackOverflow is not in the business of answering hypothetical questions. From the [faq]: *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.*

Comment: But i tagged this question in VB.NET and i've specified also the language in the question, and thnx for reopening :)

Comment: Yes, but I doubt you are working in PHP and VB.NET *at the same time.*  If you are, I apologize, but we don't necessarily want this question asked for [every possible language.]

Comment: yup, but i need the same function in 2 different languages for different reason. Want it in PHP to measure how much i save bandwidth using compression, and want to use it in VB to use a tool for showing data received/sent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of code that grabs the number of bytes received by the first IPv4 interface .(I set a label to the number, but of course you can do whatever with the number.)

```
Dim ipv4Stats As System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPv4InterfaceStatistics

ipv4Stats = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces(0).GetIPv4Statistics
Label1.Text = ipv4Stats.BytesReceived.ToString
```

I guess if you wanted it to automagically update or something, you could tie it to a timer or something.